# Automating a batch file ftp download

Tags: batch-file, ftp

Ok I have a pretty large batch program I am building to control power on over 100 DRAC ports and everything is built, tested, and working. However; I would like to have it automatically download plink.exe into the c:\directory over ftp from the download website just by having coworkers answer either yes or no to a question regarding whether or not they have installed the program on their local machine so they don't have to browse for it.
Here is the section I've been working on:

```
SET /p ANSWER=Have you downloaded plink.exe (Y/N)?
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={Y} (goto :Continue)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={N} (goto :Download)
:Download
echo Starting Plink.exe download!!!
timeout /t 2
Site from which I will be downloading:
ftp://ftp.blahblahblah.com
:Continue
```

Comment: You could encode plink.exe into the batch file using techniques that you'll find here and there.  carlos from www.dostips.com wrote VBS routines to encode and decode an executable.

Answer (score 0):

To automate commands to the built in ftp.exe on windows you have to store them in a seperate file

```
:start
SET /p ANSWER=Have you downloaded plink.exe (Y/N)?
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={Y} (goto :Continue)
if /i {%ANSWER%}=={N} (goto :Download)
goto start

:Download
echo Starting Plink.exe download!!!
rem timeout using ping command
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 2000 >NUL

rem Write the commands - remove the ones you don't need, such as username and password
echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo bin>> ftpcmd.dat
echo get plink.exe>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat

rem run ftp command
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat ftp.blahblahblah.com

rem delete the extra file.
del ftpcmd.dat

:Continue
```

Martyn

Comment: Just a thought, plink is pretty small in size, if the batch file is going on the machines, why not deploy plink with the batch?